# Use a thread as an object

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, object

How would I use a thread as an object? I attempted to do this.

Object class

```
public class Object implements Runnable{
public String name = "";
public void run(){
  //logic code here
}
}
```

And I called it by doing this.

```
Thread contract1 = new Thread(new Object());
    contract1.name = "foo";
    contract1.start();
```

I get the error

```
The field Thread.name is not visible
```

What would be the most resourceful way to do this and with the shortest amount of code needed?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't name your class `Object`. It already exists in Java.

Comment: So your `Object` class has an _accessible_ field named `name`, not the `Thread` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class YourRunnable implements Runnable{
   private String name;

   public YourRunnable(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void run() {
      //logic code here
   }
}
```

And then

```
Thread contract1 = new Thread(new YourRunnable("foo"));
contract1.start();
```

So use constructors.

EDIT: But to do what you wanted to do, all you would do is

```
public class YourRunnable implements Runnable{
   public String name;

   public void run() {
      //logic code here
   }
}
```

and then

```
YourRunnable yourRunnable = new YourRunnable();
Thread contract1 = new Thread(yourRunnable);
yourRunnable.name = "foo";
contract1.start();
```

Comment: Using constructors is great. But the question was how to access the members of `YourRunnable`, and there may be cases where that is actually needed.

Comment: @mastov well in his particular case where he just initializes the variable inside the other class, honestly, the solution is to use a constructor.

Comment: Just saying that the question might be broader than what the code itself suggests. Thanks for the edit. Upvote now.

Comment: And that's the reason we use private fields with public getters and setters :)

Comment: @chillworld agreed, getter+setter is a good choice, I never forget them in real code; I just wanted to show this one with minimal alteration compared to the original

Comment: I understand it. Just a habit pointing to that created by code review.  And its not a bad one ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your code you're trying to change the name of the thread. What you really want to do is change the name of the object that the thread is calling. You can do this in a constructor, or by declaring the object and setting the name before creating the new thread.

> 1) By creating a  constructor:

```
public class SomeObject implements Runnable{
   private String name;

   public SomeObject(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   ...
}
```

Then the declaration would look like this:

```
Thread contract1 = new Thread(new SomeObject("myNamehere"));
contract1.start();
```

> 2) Via setting the name (which is what I think you intended to do):

```
SomeObject contractObject1 = new SomeObject();
contractObject1.name = "myNamehere";
Thread contract1 = new Thread(contractObject1);
contract1.start();
```